# How pass category id from onsen-view to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm getting data from a PHP file in JSON format and "foreached" it in view.

How do I pass the category id from view to controller?

View:

```
<div ng-controller="listItems">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="list-group-item" dir-paginate="post in phones | itemsPerPage: 10" total-items="totalUsers" current-page="pagination.current">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <img src="/small/{{post.name}}" class="img-rounded col-md-1" alt="">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{post.name1}}</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">
                {{post.text1}}</p><div class="clearfix"></div>
              </a>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Controller JS:

```
    function getResultsPage(pageNumber) {
        $http.get('/calk.php?page=' + pageNumber + '&cat=' + 'CAT-ID-HERE')
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.phones = result.data.records;
                $scope.totalUsers = result.data.count
            });
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is that category id? In every post? When do you want to pass it? On click? Please give some more information.

Comment: Category id may put on view in somewhere place. When this view is working category id passing in controller on load, not whith click or hover, just when open view.

Comment: If I understood correctly it has nothing to do with the view. I think what you need is to assign the data you want to a variable like `window.myObj = "<?php echo $categoryID; >";`, and then access to it from angular: `$scope.CategoryID = window.myObj;`

Comment: I'm doing mobile app, and php in view isn't allowed. I want to pass cat id, when I click on each post in list of posts. Somethink like this:  <a ng-click="cat.id"> ... Then tis ID goes in controler.js here ->> $http.get('/calk.php?page=' + pageNumber + '&cat=' + 'CAT-ID-HERE')

Comment: Well, in your previous comment you said "not with click or hover, just when open view". If you want to do it on click after all, then just make a function in your controller `$scope.myFunction = function(catID) { $scope.catID = catID; }` and call it from the view: `ng-click="myFunction(cat.id)"`.